# How to change the size of nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, dimensions

How is it possible to change the size of a node, for example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw  node[fill,circle]{} (0,0);%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How to make the circle smaller or larger?

Comment: Related Question: [Size of TikZ ellipse node](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103557/size-of-tikz-ellipse-node).

Comment: @student I’m sure you use place nodes differently (“more corrent”) by now, though I want to add for other visitors, that you actually do not `draw` the node but only `fill` it (despite the `\draw`, yes). Also the node is only placed by default at `(0,0)`. The last `(0,0)` bit is just a move to the coordinate `(0,0)`.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

The node size normally depends on the size of the content. Your node is empty so it is relative small. If you want to set the size manually use the `minimum width` and/or `minimum height` or set both at the same time using `minimum size`.

The `circle` shapes just uses the greatest of both values, otherwise you may be interested in the [`ellipse` shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103557/size-of-tikz-ellipse-node).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw node[fill,circle,minimum size=2cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you want to mark the node even smaller than it is in your question, set the `inner sep` value lower. It causes an empty node to still have some size. Best set it to `0pt` and then use `minimum size`.

If you only `fill` the node and do not draw its border (as you do in your example despite the `\draw` command (that does not affect nodes on the path)), you might also set the `outer sep` to `0pt`, so that paths will actually connect to it.
If you do not reference the node later, you could actually just use the `circle` path operator, where you can specify a radius very simple: `\draw (0,0) circle [radius=<value>];`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw  node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1pt] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: can you set a default value for "minimum size" within a document?

Comment: @drevicko: Try `\tikzset{minimum size=..}`. If this doesn't work check the PGF/TikZ manual for an "every node" or similar setting.

Comment: `inner sep` reduces the horizontal size of the node. How can I reduce the vertical size?

Comment: @EliasStrehle: `inner sep` reduces both the horizontal and vertical size. There is apparently something else there in your case which caues the vertical size.

Answer (score 54):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw  node[fill,circle,scale=0.3]{} (0,0);%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Note that the size of the empty node is determined by `inner sep` and `scale` simply scales this down in your code.

Comment: scale is good. Pay attention however that it does affect also the coordinate at which you want to place your node in as well as xshift and yshift properties of the node. A better option might be inner sep = 0.3ex instead of scale = 0.3 for example try this \node[circle, inner sep = 0.3ex, thick, fill, black] at (30: 15ex) (mynode){};