# Change width of arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

This is a MWE of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}


\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style={
        draw,
        fill=black,
        single arrow,
        minimum height=2.5ex,
        line width=1pt,
        single arrow head extend=0.1ex
    }
}

\newcommand{\arrowup}{%
\tikz [baseline=-0.5ex]{\node [myarrow,rotate=90] {};}
}
\newcommand{\arrowdown}{%
\tikz [baseline=-1ex]{\node [myarrow,rotate=-90] {};}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
This is some text.\\
\arrowdown\\
And some more.\\
\arrowup\\
And even more.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

which gives me this:

[image: arrows]

the `line width` will only reduce the width of the arrows up to a certain point but no more. I want the arrows to look a little thinner. I'm using `PDFLaTeX` to compile on Ubuntu 12.10. Cheers.

Comment: You have to set `inner sep=1pt` (or an even smaller value). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13587/how-to-change-the-size-of-nodes

Comment: Thank you, adding that line and fiddling with the rest helped me get the width right. The answer given is pretty much your comment so I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For  tweaking an arrow node the TiKz manual lists the following options: `single arrow head extend`, `inner sep=` and `single arrow head indent`. I'd like to add the `yscale` or `xscale` options. Playing with these values you may get the  desired appearance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style={
        draw,
        fill=black,
        single arrow,
        minimum height=2.5ex,
        line width=1pt,
        single arrow head extend=0.1ex
    }
}

\newcommand{\arrowup}{%
\tikz [baseline=-0.5ex]{\node [myarrow,rotate=90, single arrow head extend=2mm,inner sep=.1mm] {};}% or: single arrow head indent=⟨length⟩
}
\newcommand{\arrowdown}{%
\tikz [baseline=-1ex]{\node [myarrow,rotate=-90,  yscale=.5, single arrow head extend=1mm] {};}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
This is some text.\\
\arrowdown\\
And some more.\\
\arrowup\\
And even more.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

In this example i especially like the second (down) arrow.

Comment: Thank you, the `inner sep=` line did the trick. Regards.