# Size of TikZ ellipse node

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, nodes

When I set the `minimum size` of an ellipse in a `tikzpicture` environment, it expands into a circle if the inner content does not grow as large as the ellipse shape itself.

Is there any way around it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, ellipse, minimum size=100pt,
    align=center]
\node (a) {Alpha};
\node[left=150pt, below=30pt] (b) at (a) {Beta};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It seems to me that, without something as wide as the ellipse length, TikZ is not able to define the width and height of the ellipse, but how can I set these variables?

Comment: The `minimum size` style simply sets `minimum width` and `minimum height` (to the same provided value). If the contents are neither higher nor wider than those values the shape will be a circle.

Comment: Very related: [How to change the size of nodes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13587) also take a look at [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372) Although this is only a MWE, you may also be interested in [the `positioning` library](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94396).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can set `minimum height=<length>`, or `minimum width=<length>` as shown in MWE:

[image]

### Notes:

- As Qrrbrbirlbel commented, setting `minimum size` is setting *both* the values of `minimum width` and `minimum height` and hence you end up with a circle.
- If you want to specify *both* the `minimum height=` and `minimum width=` parameters you need to set them to different values, otherwise you will again end up with a circle.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[ultra thick, draw=blue, ellipse, minimum width=100pt,
    align=center]
\node (a) {Alpha};
\node[left=150pt, below=30pt] (b) at (a) {Beta};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 And that's an else. That's really something else (: Didn't know this `width` argument. Thanks!

Comment: @Rubens You can also set the size of the TeX box (that is used inside the node) with `text width`, `text height` and `text depth`. Those are explicitly not minimum values and have very different outputs than the `minimum` values. They also need the `align=center` option to center the content.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Hmmm, Good point. I think that that is a _more_ correct solution. You want to post an answer?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Yeah, sloppy verbiage. Have clarified, I think?