# Vertical ellipse node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

How can I make this ellipse node vertical (height > width).
My attempt with `` does not seem to work.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\fill[gray!20!white] (-0.5,-0.4)rectangle(0.5,0.4);
\node at (0,0) [ellipse, minimum height =2,draw] (V) {\makebox[1.4\width][c]{x}}; 
\draw(V) to coordinate[pos=0.9](D1)  (-0.5,0.4);
\draw (V) -- (-0.5,-0.4);
\draw (V) to coordinate[pos=0.9](D2) (-0.5, -0.15);
\node at  (-0.4,0.13) {\vdots};
\draw (V) -- (0.5,-0.4);
\draw (V) -- (0.5, -0.15);
\draw (V) -- (0.5,0.4);
\node at (0.4,0.13) {\vdots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/85d2c38b78407e5b1ba42140dfd11fcdf8df1edf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex#L12-L194) shows `ellipse` shape doesn't make use of key `shape aspect`. Currently one has to use indirect options like `inner xsep/ysep` and/or `minimum width/height` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103558).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: Thanks. But pgfkeys does not recognize neither `minimum width/height` nor `inner xsep/ysep`. The post you linked uses `minimum height`, so I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Try `minimum height=3em` instead of `minimum height=3`. If the value is unit-less, `pt` is used so the effect would be almost invisible (unless you pass a huge number).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: That worked! Many thanks