# Two questions about nodes at Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I saw this question [How to change the size of nodes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13587/how-to-change-the-size-of-nodes) and I wonder:

1. If I want the nodes will be at the same size as `automata` nodes, what I need to fill at size? (or the scale).
2. If I want make it for all the nodes (I assuming I need to write it at the beginning), what I need to write?

Here is an MWE:

```
 % Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.1-1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] (1) {$1$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,1) node[circle,draw] {$1$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28557).

Comment: @heblyx, your code contais a lot of non related commands, including font changing. It is not *Minimal* (MWE).

Comment: @Sigur, I edit my MWE, now it's better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I interpret the question slightly different than Phelype. If you want all nodes in that picture to have the same size as the `state` nodes that come with `automata`, you only need to say `every node/.append style={minimum width=2.5em}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] (1) {$1$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={minimum width=2.5em}]
\draw (1,1) node[circle,draw] {$1$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ooh, much simpler certainly :D

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I don't know who of us gave the "correct" answer, if any. Let's see. ;-)

Comment: Both of you gave me a great answers! Really - so first of all - Thank you for both! :)

The reason I accept your answer @marmot it's because it simpler - but both answers were great and answer my questions!

Answer (score 4):

When you draw a `\node [state]`, you are drawing a `\node [circle,draw,minimum size=2.5em,every state]`.

How to figure this out:

The `\usetikzlibrary{<library>}` command loads a `tikzlibrary<library>.code.tex` file. Searching for the `tikzlibraryautomata.code.tex` file in my TeX distribution I found it at `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/`.

I opened the file and searched for `state` and found at the end of the file:

```
\tikzstyle{state}=                [state without output]
```

so `state` is the same as `state without output`. Searching for the latter I found:

```
\tikzstyle{state without output}=  [circle,draw,minimum size=2.5em,every state]
```

thus, `state` is the same as `circle,draw,minimum size=2.5em,every state`, with `every state` being empty by default:

```
\tikzstyle{every state}=           []
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] (1) {$1$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,1) node [circle,draw,minimum size=2.5em,every state] {$1$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

Oh, and answering your second question, you can use more or less the same approach as in the package, but change the `every node` style. To change it globally you can use `\tikzset`:

```
\tikzset{
  every node/.style = {
    circle,draw,minimum size=2.5em,every state
  }
}
```

or, for a single `tikzpicture`, you can pass this as an option:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style = {
    circle,draw,minimum size=2.5em,every state
  }
]
\draw (1,1) node {$1$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimum example to set the size of `state` to known value.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every state/.style={minimum size=2cm},]
\node[state] (1) {$1$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,1) node[circle,draw,minimum size=2cm] {$1$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]